# Missing } after property list, can't find it

Tags: mongodb-query

I don't fully understand jquery yet but I am in the middle of a course to learn some.

Part of my course required me to enter:

```
db.grades.aggregate(
    {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'average':{'$avg':'$score'}}},
    {'$sort':{'average':-1}},
    {'$limit':1}
                   )
```

It is throwing this error:

```
[thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell)1:39
```

I can't see the missing }, can someone please help me?

Comment: This is not jQuery, it's mongodb.

Comment: The problem is not in the quoted code.

Comment: Check if $group or $sort variables have a single quote (')

Comment: Thanks for the note I have removed the jquery tag - while searching I saw similar problems with similar syntax and the tag was suggested when I was writing the question. As per the marked answer below, putting the aggregate pipe into an array solved the issue. This is directly from a course offered by mongodb so I'm quite surprised by the the omission!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array

```
db.grades.aggregate([
    {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'average':{'$avg':'$score'}}},
    {'$sort':{'average':-1}},
    {'$limit':1}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This has worked. I assume I made a mistake when I asked this as it was voted down 4 times within a minute! Any advice?

Comment: @JakeStokes No problem..glad to help..you can thank me by upvoting and accepting my answer

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate pipes must be in an array, check the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

```
db.grades.aggregate([
    {'$group':{'_id':'$student_id', 'average':{'$avg':'$score'}}},
    {'$sort':{'average':-1}},
    {'$limit':1}
])
```